# Can Rayami, First of the Fallen's ability give it Annihilator or Monstrosity?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a creature with Annihilator or Monstrosity dies, could [Rayami, First of the Fallen](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRayami%2c%20First%20of%20the%20Fallen%5d) obtain those abilities?

Comment: As a side note, Monstrosity is not actually a keyword ability; it is a keyword action. In other words, it is not an ability on its own, it is just an instruction that can appear in the effects of some abilities.

Answer (score 4):

No. [Rayami, First of the Fallen](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRayami%2c%20First%20of%20the%20Fallen%5d)'s ability obtains only the keyword abilities it lists. Any other ability not listed cannot be obtained by that ability. Monstrosity and Annihilator are not listed, so can't be picked up.

In case it helps: the abilities listed on Rayami is the current list of evergreen keyword abilities. (Except Defender.) No set-specific keywords will be found on that list.

Comment: Fortunately the list doesn't contain Defender!  That would be a bad one to have to take.  Another great reason it has to be restricted to a specific list.

Comment: And if one were to use Rayami's ability, it is a replacement ability, so technically the other creature doesn't die.